# Error 3 uploading video to Google Photos with Powershell (Works for pictures)

Tags: powershell, rest, google-photos-api

I am using the following code to upload photos and videos to Google Photos using Powershell. The code works perfectly for pictures, but will fail when uploading a video (which is accepted in Google Photos when this is uploaded through a browser).

When attempting to upload a video, raw bytes upload will succeed, but `mediaItems.batchCreate` will fail with status.code `3` and status.message `"Failed: There was an error while trying to create this media item."`
Could this be due to a wrong mime type in the header?

```
Function GP-UploadMedia (){
    <# 
    .SYNOPSIS
      Uploads a Google Photos media (picture/video)
    
    .Description  
      Parameters: 
        - album id
        - media path
      Returns:
        - picture id

    #>
    [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$album_id,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
            [string]$media_path

        )

    # refresh tokens if required
    G-RefreshTokens
    
    # 1st step: upload raw bytes
    $requestUri = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads"
    $mime_type = [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($media_path);
    $Headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $($Global:Tokens.access_token)";
        ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        "X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type" = $mime_type;
        "X-Goog-Upload-Protocol" = "raw";
        }

    $body = $media_path;

    try {
        $upload_token = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -InFile $body -Uri $requestUri -Method POST
    }
    catch {
        # Something went wrong. Investigate!
        dieOnError ([System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()));
    }
 
    # refresh tokens if required
    G-RefreshTokens

    # 2nd step: pair raw bytes to Google Photo media (picture/video)
    $requestUri = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate"
    $Headers = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $($Global:Tokens.access_token)";
        }
  
    $body = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
        albumId = $album_id;
        newMediaItems = @( 
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                description = "";
                simpleMediaItem = [PSCustomObject]@{ 
                    fileName = (Split-Path $media_path -leaf);
                    uploadToken = $upload_token;
                    }
            }
        )
    } 
    $myJson = $body|ConvertTo-Json -Depth 4

    try {
        $Response = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers $Headers -Body ($myJson)  -Uri $requestUri -Method POST -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    }
    catch {
         # Something went wrong. Investigate!
         dieOnError ([System.IO.StreamReader]::new($_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()));
    } 

    return  $Response.newMediaItemResults.MediaItem.id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution to your issue, when your script is modified as follows, is that the direct solution to your issue? In this case, please modify the request header of "1st step: upload raw bytes" as follows.

#### From:

```
ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

#### To:

```
"Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
```

#### Note:

- When I tested your script, I could replicate the same situation with you. And, when I modified your script with the above modification, I could confirm that the issue could be resolved. So, please test the above modification.

Comment: @Riccardo Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When I saw your script, I could notice it by chance. And, happy New Year to you too!

Comment: @Kanshi, I have read your profile, you could create a Linkedin account, I guess you would receive contacts from there too, as your CV is impressive. Keep it going!

Comment: @Riccardo Thank you for the comment. I'm honored about it.